# Get data from custom cell to TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITextField` in my custom `UITableViewCell`, and I need to get input text to my `UITableViewController`, when I press button. My code:

```
class DotextFieldTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}

class NewTodoTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    @IBAction func createTodo(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: to get any text you need is textField.text

Comment: I don't know how to access to Textfield.text from my ViewController

Answer (score 0):

just use the method and cast your cell class to DotextFieldTableViewCell

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DotextFieldTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}
```

And after that you can use

```
let someText = cell.textField.text
```

Comment: I already did it. I don't know how to return value back to my view controller, after pressing button

Comment: if you did everything right so let someText = cell.textField.text should save your text in someTxt